# 4-bit counter using logic elements: output is always 0

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I am trying to build a 4-bit counter in system Verilog using logical elements only. I am using simple D-flipflops with some XOR and AND logic to achieve this.
However, while simulating, the Output values are constantly 0, and I am not sure what's the issue.

**Code:**

```
 module d_flipflop (
    input reg Enable,
    input logic clk,
    output reg Out
    );

   always @(posedge clk)
   begin
   Out <= Enable;

   end

endmodule

module Four_bitCounter (
  input reg Enable,
  input logic clk,
  output reg out0, out1, out2, out3
   );

  logic ffInput0;
  logic ffInput1;
  logic ffInput2;
  logic ffInput3;

  always @(*) begin
    ffInput0 <= out0 ^ Enable;
    ffInput1 <= out1 ^ (Enable & out0);
    ffInput2 <= out2 ^ (Enable & out1);
    ffInput3 <= out3 ^ (Enable & out2);
   end


  d_flipflop dff0 (
    .Enable(ffInput0),
    .clk (clk),
    .Out (out0)

      );



     d_flipflop dff1 (
      .Enable(ffInput1),
      .clk (clk),
      .Out (out1)

       );


      d_flipflop dff2 (
       .Enable(ffInput2),
       .clk (clk),
       .Out (out2)

        );


      d_flipflop dff3 (
       .Enable(ffInput3),
       .clk (clk),
       .Out (out3)

        );




  endmodule
```

**TestBench file:**

```
  module Four_bitCounter_tb();

       reg out0, out1, out2, out3;
       logic clk;
       reg Enable;



   Four_bitCounter F_bc0 (
    .Enable(Enable),
    .clk (clk),
    .out0 (out0),
    .out1 (out1),
    .out2 (out2),
    .out3 (out3)
      );

   initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #10 clk = ~clk;

     end


     initial begin
      out0 <= 1 'b0;
      out1 <= 1 'b0;
      out2 <= 1 'b0;
      out3 <= 1 'b0;
       Enable <= 1 'b0; 


    #20

     Enable <= 1 'b1;

     #300

    $finish;



     end


     endmodule
```

**Simulation :**

[image: Simulation Wave of 4-bitCounter]

**Design:**

[image: RTL Viewer Design]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to compile your code, I get errors with multiple simulators.

In the testbench, the `out0` signal has multiple drivers.  The same for the other 3 "out" signals.  Since they are outputs of the design, you should not make assignments to them in the testbench.  Also you should declare them as `wire`, not `reg`.  Here is the modified testbench:

```
module Four_bitCounter_tb();
    wire out0, out1, out2, out3;
    logic clk;
    reg Enable;

    Four_bitCounter F_bc0 (
        .Enable(Enable),
        .clk  (clk),
        .out0 (out0),
        .out1 (out1),
        .out2 (out2),
        .out3 (out3)
    );

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #10 clk = ~clk;
    end

    initial begin
        Enable <= 1'b0; 
        #20
        Enable <= 1'b1;
        #300
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

After that change, I see unknowns (X) on the outputs.  This happens because the flipflop `Out` is `X` at time 0.  All `reg` types are initialized to X.  You need a way to initialize them to 0.  For simulations, change:

```
output reg Out
```

to:

```
output reg Out = 0
```

---

Alternately, to get rid of unknown values at the start of simulation, you could use a [reset signal for your design](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf).

---

You should sign up for a free account on edaplayground; this will give you access to other simulators where you might get better information about why your simulation misbehaves.